# Click Record Button at about:tracing through Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, shadow-dom

I am trying to click the Record button through Selenium in Google Chrome. However I am not able to. Element is not found. I have tried using id and xpath. None of them worked.

`WebElement record = driver.findElement(By.id("record-button"));
record.click();`

The HTML code is

```
<template id="profiling-view-template">
  <tr-ui-b-info-bar-group></tr-ui-b-info-bar-group>
  <x-timeline-view-buttons>
    <button id="record-button">Record</button>
    <button id="save-button">Save</button>
    <button id="load-button">Load</button>
  </x-timeline-view-buttons>
  <tr-ui-timeline-view>
    <track-view-container id="track_view_container"></track-view-container>
  </tr-ui-timeline-view>
</template>
```

Any lead will be appreciated.

Comment: please share relevant html code

Comment: You will have to share more code: Is this inside of a frame? Is this in shadow-DOM? Is there a lot of AJAX?

Comment: I am not sure about AJAX or shadow-DOM. However you can find it easily by opening "chrome://tracing" as url in Google Chrome

Comment: That uses shadow-DOM. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48286398/3124333

Comment: Thankyou.. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to access that object by this

`WebElement root1 = driver.findElement(By.tagName("tr-ui-timeline-view"));
        WebElement shadowRoot1 = expandRootElement(root1);
        WebElement record1 = shadowRoot1.findElement(By.id("record-button"));
        record1.click();`

`public WebElement expandRootElement(WebElement element) {
        WebElement ele = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot",
                element);
        return ele;
    }`