# How to handle shadowdom in SeleniumWebdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

I'm trying to work with this dom with c# WebDriver. My chromedriver uses v38.
I can't use input#frameworkInput as everything under #shadow-root is not seen.
So I tried

```
IWebElement ele = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
```

but this is just bringing back the exception shadowRoot not found. I've tried some suggestions here, but they don't seem to work. Any pointers?

[image: This is the dom]

Comment: I am reading it now to see what it offers

Comment: Having read it, I notice that it recommends using something which consistently returns null for me -> return arguments[0].shadowRoot

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question

```
element1
(shadowdom)
element2 
(shadowdom)
element3
```

I was thinking that I could access arguments[0].shadowRoot directly from the dom
Infact I have to get element1, query it for a shadowRoot, get element2, query it for a shadowRoot, then I can find element3.
It wasn't what I expected, most probably I failed to understand previous posts on the subject.(?) Most helpful answer was [selenium webdriver (chromedriver) and accessing shadow dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286398/selenium-webdriver-chromedriver-and-accessing-shadow-dom/48287384#48287384)

Comment: It would, but this was posted a year ago and I no longer have the snippet.