# How to input text in a textbox that is under Shadow-root in a web page using protractor or selenium.

Tags: selenium, xpath, protractor, automated-tests, shadow-dom

How to input text in a text-box that is under Shadow-root in a web page using protractor or selenium? Anything would be helpful.
I am trying to enter values in a text-field with xpath and xpath is correct because I have validated it in console.

Comment: Can you add a public URL having such use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle elements inside Shadow-root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384458/how-to-handle-elements-inside-shadow-root)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using javascript in the web console you can use the following:

```
document.querySelector('message-list').shadowRoot.querySelector('.textbox').querySelector('textbox').value = 'hello'
```

To run it with appium you need to use driver.executeScript

Comment: Be aware that this will only work if the shadowRoot was created "open" is the developer chooses to do this: `this.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'}); then `element.shadowRoot` will return `null`