# How click on a button under a CLOSED shadow DOM with selenium for python?

Tags: python, selenium, button, selector, shadow-dom

I'm looking to access to the button but the CLOSED shadow DOM block me, how can i switch it to open and have access to this button ?

```html
<div class="button-holder help-button-holder">
  #shadow-root (closed)
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome-extension://mpbjkejclgfgadiemmefgebjfooflfhl/src/solve/solver-button.css">
    <button tabindex="0" title="Solve the challenge" id="solver-button"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automate shadow DOM elements using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77242284/how-to-locate-element-in-shadow-root-closed-host

Answer (score 1):

I have encounter the same problem and manager to work around it.

So the idea is to focus on the closest element before "shadow-root (closed)", then use Tab key to reach that solver button, then click it.

I work on Kotlin, but you should be able to attempt for python.

```
// click to focus on the solver button wrapper
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".button-holder.help-button-holder")).click()

// use Actions instead of pointing to the solver button itself
val actions = Actions(driver)
actions.sendKeys(Keys.TAB)
actions.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root

outer = expand_shadow_element(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".button-holder.help-button-holder"))
inner = outer.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@id='solver-button']")
inner.click()
```

You can do the following to click the element inside the shadow root.

Comment: It says that outer has no attribute 'find_element_by_id' ...

Comment: Try the following fix.