# Selecting button within closed Shadow DOM, with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha, shadow-dom

I am trying to solve a google captcha with Selenium, using python

I'm using [this](https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/) simple example site to test with, but I am having difficulties understanding how to select a button that is within a shadow root.

This image shows the button element I need to get.
[image]

I understand I need to get the outer div element first, then search for the inner element, but I'm failing to do so, as I am not 100% clear on how to navigate to the inner element after executing something like

`driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('div[class=\"button-holder help-button-holder\"]')`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67141915/how-click-on-a-button-under-a-closed-shadow-dom-with-selenium-for-python) question is on similar (same?) problem, but there is no working solution.

Comment: Did you find some solution?

Comment: I did not, still suffering through manually solving those captchas

Answer (score 0):

Your element is placed in `shadow-root` with `closed` state.

When the mode of a shadow root is "closed", the shadow root's implementation internals are inaccessible and unchangeable, so you can't access `shadowRoot` property.

Since Selenium implemented CDP protocol API, `shadow-root` with `closed` state can be overridden with `open` state on page load.

You just need to override `Element` class prototype method `attachShadow` and evaluate script on new document before page load.

[How to override Element properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54954525/20292589)

[How to executed script on load via CDP Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68532593/20292589)

**Example of code:**

```py
url = "yourUrl"
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument', {'source': """
Element.prototype._attachShadow = Element.prototype.attachShadow;
Element.prototype.attachShadow = function () {
    return this._attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
};
"""})
driver.get(url)
closed_shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class=\"button-holder help-button-holder\"]')
shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', closed_shadow_host)
```