# Python Selenium Cant Find Elements Of Dropdown menu

Tags: python, selenium

Im a beginner in python and selenium, Ive been trying to make selenium click on the dropdown menu. Ive tried alot of solutions but none worked.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSREc.png)

This is my code

```
driver.get('chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Fmeet.google.com%3A443')
time.sleep(3)
microphone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@aria-label='Microphone']")
```

This is the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@aria-label='Microphone']"}
```

Is there anything i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This element is located inside multiple shadow-roots.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium) for more details how to deal with shadow DOM.