# Selenium and tiktok accept cookied button

Tags: python, selenium

So I am having problems with my code. Everytime i run it, I cannot click on the 'Accept Cookies'Button on the tiktok page I am trying to access. It simply just gives me a Timeoutexception error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium_stealth import stealth
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install() 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.tiktok.com/tag/reizen?lang=en')


WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "/html/body/tiktok-cookie-banner//div")))
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/tiktok-cookie-banner//div/div[2]"))).click()
```

I am not sure where the problem is.

Many thanks!

Comment: I can't see there element matching `/html/body/tiktok-cookie-banner//div` XPath. Are you sure it is there?

Comment: Can you explain a little. Not sure I fully understand. Thanks!

Comment: I have opened the URL you are using here in a new incognito browser and I see no elements matching the above locator. Also no any kind of accept cookies banners appeared.

Comment: Interesting, I do. Even in incogenito. Is there some settings I can change to prevent the cookies coming up when I run in selenium?

Comment: Since I can't reproduce that I don't know

Answer (score 0):

What I noticed when using the Selenium head to manually debug is that the `cookie` element does not show up on my machine. If you have anything on your browser/machine that could be preventing the cookie popup, that may be a factor.

An additional problem is that the `tiktok-cookie-banner` element uses the shadow DOM, which introduces a whole separate element of complexity. To solve this problem, I recommend the [shadow-automation-selenium](https://github.com/sukgu/shadow-automation-selenium) package, which the documentation explains how to use to interact with the element you are interested in. More information about the shadow DOM can be found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55761810/6456163).