# Converting SearchContext to WebElement in Selenium with Java on Chrome

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, shadow-root

Service Now has changed to using shadow root like this

<span id='s1'>

   #shadow-root

   <button>Cancel</button>

   <button>Submit</button>

</span>

I can easily get the first span:

```
 WebElement sele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='s1']"));
```

And then get the shadow root:

```
 SearchContext sc = sele.getShadowRoot();
```

But it will not let you do a

```
 sc.findElements(By.xpath(".//button'"));
```

or more preferably

```
 WebElement cancelButton = sc.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[.='Cancel']"));
```

You have to find with CS selector

```
 sc.findElements(By.cssSelector(" button"));
```

and go through each button to get the text.  To make it worse, when I try

```
 List<WebElement> buttons = sc.findElements(By.cssSelector(" button"));
```

because it says there is an error with "=" and it expects "<=".  No idea why.  Have to do a

```
 for (WebElement wele : sc.findElements(By.cssSelector(" button")) {
   String txt = wele.getText();
   if (txt.equals("Cancel")) ... // whatever you want
 }
```

So my question is is there someway to convert "sc" to a WebElement?  Even maybe someway to get itself?  The equivalent of

```
 sc.findElement(By.xpath("."));
```

or someway to look for xpath with SearchContext?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55761810/3485434) is exactly what you looking for.
There are several answers given there to get the Shadow Root as a `WebElement` object.

Comment: That does not work anymore.  Someone mentioned you cannot do that with the new Selenium, use javascriptExecutor to cast SearchContext to WebElement

Comment: Ah, OK. thank you for letting me to know that. BTW this is why I didn't close this question as duplicate since I wasn't sure it working on Selenium 4...