# Selenium/Python: no such element with: driver.find_element(By.ID)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I try to locate elements on a website which are in a form to then send keys to login but I get an error, see below:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="username"]"}
```

Line of code is:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").send_keys("test123")
```

For HTML code see:

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/604Aj.png)

I use latest version of Python/Selenium and PyCharm.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Maybe it's inside a iframe. Please provide more of the html in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in that line of code. Try one of the below

- **Try applying implicit wait as below:**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

- **Check if there is a frame/ iframe covering this element, if yes, try below code before locating the element**

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("<XPath expression of the frame>")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

To switch back to the main DOM:

`driver.switch_to.default_content()`

- **If the frame doesn't exist, then try inducing explicit wait as below:**

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username"))
```

Below imports you will require:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

[image: html]

the element is a `<input>` element which would accept text input using `send_keys()` method.

---

### Solution

Ideally to send a *character sequence* to an `<input>` element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input#username[name='username']"))).send_keys("Coding_89")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='input' and @id='username'][@name='username']"))).send_keys("Coding_89")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer unfortunately I get the following error on Using XPATH: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:

Comment: @Coding_89 Check if the desired element is within an [**iframe**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) or within a [**shadowRoot**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73242476/7429447)

Comment: I looked a bit deeper into the HTML code and i think its because it is a form not an iframe, i changed the picture in the original post to provide more of the HTML code