# Enter text in a div using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Hello i am new to selenium and self learning. My question is for the below webpage. I want the python program to enter some data into the search field.

I have tried various versions of samples i could find here but unable to understand what i am doing wrong here.

1. `enter_customer_name =  driver.find_element("id" ,r"vaadin-text-field-input-0")`
2. `enter_customer_name =  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "vaadin-text-field-container")`
3. `driver.find_element("id","vaadin-text-field-label-0") enter_customer_name.send_keys("TEST")`
4. `enter_customer_name = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "name")`

HTML snapshot:

[image]

Not sure what i am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

[image: html]

to enter some data into the search field instead of the `<div>` you need to traverse a bit deeper to the `<input>` tag.

---

### Solution

To send a *character sequence* to the element ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.vaadin-text-field-container div[part='input-field'] slot[name='input'] > input[part='value']"))).send_keys("text")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='vaadin-text-field-container']//div[@part='input-field']//slot[@name='input']/input[@part='value']"))).send_keys("gautamraj")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. 
I am getting a Timeout error when i tried to run it with above suggestion.
"  raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException"

Comment: As there is a class in the first div should i add the class as well?
div[class='vaadin-text-field-container'] div[part='input-field'] slot[name='input'] > input[part='value']

Is this a correct way to parse into the inner loop?

Comment: File "C:/Users/s7578437/.spyder-py3/Selenium_Mock.py", line 29, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.vaadin-text-field-container div[part='input-field'] slot[name='input'] > input[part='value']"))).send_keys("TEST")

  File "C:\Users\s7578437\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException

Comment: Still getting the same error for both the methods.

Comment: Check if the desired element is within an [**iframe**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) or within a [**shadowRoot**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73242476/7429447)

Comment: It is within a Shadowroot.

Comment: @gautamraj You already have the link to the detailed explaination. Do you still need help?

Comment: I will give the link you provided a try and see if the shadowRoot can be parsed. Thank you so much for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi i am unable to come up with a right logic to parse the shadow root to the input where i am able to enter any text.

shadow = Shadow(driver)
shadow_host = shadow.find_element('#vaadin-text-field-container')
value = "TEST"
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1])",shadow_host, value)
Am i using the logic wrong?