# Locator for clicking the salesforce icon on top left corner of salesforce.com using javascript?

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, salesforce, shadow-dom, queryselector

I need to locate the element and click on it. With my approach i am getting `ElementNotInteractableException`.

```
WebElement salesforce =(WebElement)js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('hgf-c360nav').shadowRoot.querySelector('.c360-nav__header-logo-img')");
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Not that super clear where and why you are exactly stuck. However on my [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) system invoking the initial url:

```
https://www.salesforce.com/in/?ir=1
```

Then moving forward clicking on the **salesforce** logo using [*`document.querySelector()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55763793/7429447) I'm redirected to:

```
https://www.salesforce.com/in/?bc=HA
```

- Code Block:

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
  options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://www.salesforce.com/in/?ir=1");
  //Thread.sleep(15000);
  JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  WebElement logo = (WebElement)jse.executeScript("return document.querySelector('hgf-c360nav').shadowRoot.querySelector('.c360-nav__header-logo-img')");
  logo.click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: salesforce_icon_shadowroot]