# How to read an element text inside the shadow root

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom, shadow-root

I want to read the date value inside this shadow root.

[image: Image1]

even though I tried below it says 'no such shadow root'. How can I correct this?

```
driver.FindElement(CustomTimeHours).GetShadowRoot().FindElement(By.Id("placeholder")).Text
```

Comment: Read this post if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium

Comment: Can you give it a try : date_value = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot.getElementById("placeholder").innerText;', custom_time_hours)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automate shadow DOM elements using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium)