# Unable to click on the dropdown in the Salesforce using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

In the dropdown there is values to be selected, unable to click on the drop down. The locators XPATH is pointing to the dropdown but the click is not happening. Tried using `click()` method, `action` class and `javascript executor` click functions but the click is not happening. Observed many changes on manually clicking the dropdown one of them is

When the dropdown is opened the class name is

```
//div[@class='slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open']
```

When the dropdown is closed the class name is

```
//div[@class='slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click]
```

The HTML is below

```
<div lwc-24on3e8rogg="" class="slds-form-element__control"><lightning-base-combobox lwc-24on3e8rogg="" class="slds-combobox_container" lwc-4kb6kaqheak-host="" invalid=""><div lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-combobox_container"><div lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click"><div lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none"><button lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-combobox__input slds-input_faux" id="combobox-button-32" type="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox" data-value="" aria-label="Tipo de via, Seleccione una opción" aria-required="true" aria-controls="dropdown-element-32" aria-describedby="combobox-label-31 help-text-31"><span lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-truncate">Seleccione una opción</span></button><div lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-input__icon-group slds-input__icon-group_right"><lightning-icon lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right slds-icon-utility-down slds-icon_container" icon-name="utility:down"><span style="--sds-c-icon-color-background: var(--slds-c-icon-color-background, transparent)" part="boundary"><lightning-primitive-icon size="xx-small" variant=""><svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default slds-icon_xx-small" focusable="false" data-key="down" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 52 52" part="icon"><g><path d="M8.3 14h35.4c1 0 1.7 1.3.9 2.2L27.3 37.4c-.6.8-1.9.8-2.5 0L7.3 16.2c-.7-.9-.1-2.2 1-2.2z"></path></g></svg></lightning-primitive-icon></span></lightning-icon></div></div><div lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_fluid slds-dropdown_left" id="dropdown-element-32" data-dropdown-element="" role="listbox" part="dropdown overlay"><lightning-base-combobox-item lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-media_center slds-media_small slds-listbox__option_plain" data-item-id="combobox-button-32-0" data-value="Camino" role="option" id="combobox-button-32-0-32" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span><span class="slds-media__body"><span class="slds-truncate" title="Camino">Camino</span></span></lightning-base-combobox-item><lightning-base-combobox-item lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-media_center slds-media_small slds-listbox__option_plain" data-item-id="combobox-button-32-1" data-value="Otro" role="option" id="combobox-button-32-1-32" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span><span class="slds-media__body"><span class="slds-truncate" title="Otro">Otro</span></span></lightning-base-combobox-item><lightning-base-combobox-item lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-media_center slds-media_small slds-listbox__option_plain" data-item-id="combobox-button-32-2" data-value="Avenida" role="option" id="combobox-button-32-2-32" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span><span class="slds-media__body"><span class="slds-truncate" title="Avenida">Avenida</span></span></lightning-base-combobox-item><lightning-base-combobox-item lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-media_center slds-media_small slds-listbox__option_plain" data-item-id="combobox-button-32-3" data-value="Polígono" role="option" id="combobox-button-32-3-32" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span><span class="slds-media__body"><span class="slds-truncate" title="Polígono">Polígono</span></span></lightning-base-combobox-item><lightning-base-combobox-item lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-media_center slds-media_small slds-listbox__option_plain" data-item-id="combobox-button-32-4" data-value="Paseo" role="option" id="combobox-button-32-4-32" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span><span class="slds-media__body"><span class="slds-truncate" title="Paseo">Paseo</span></span></lightning-base-combobox-item><lightning-base-combobox-item lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-media_center slds-media_small slds-listbox__option_plain" data-item-id="combobox-button-32-5" data-value="Ronda" role="option" id="combobox-button-32-5-32" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span><span class="slds-media__body"><span class="slds-truncate" title="Ronda">Ronda</span></span></lightning-base-combobox-item><lightning-base-combobox-item lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-media_center slds-media_small slds-listbox__option_plain" data-item-id="combobox-button-32-6" data-value="Carretera" role="option" id="combobox-button-32-6-32" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span><span class="slds-media__body"><span class="slds-truncate" title="Carretera">Carretera</span></span></lightning-base-combobox-item><lightning-base-combobox-item lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-media_center slds-media_small slds-listbox__option_plain" data-item-id="combobox-button-32-7" data-value="Pasaje" role="option" id="combobox-button-32-7-32" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span><span class="slds-media__body"><span class="slds-truncate" title="Pasaje">Pasaje</span></span></lightning-base-combobox-item><lightning-base-combobox-item lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-media_center slds-media_small slds-listbox__option_plain" data-item-id="combobox-button-32-8" data-value="Rambla" role="option" id="combobox-button-32-8-32" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span><span class="slds-media__body"><span class="slds-truncate" title="Rambla">Rambla</span></span></lightning-base-combobox-item><lightning-base-combobox-item lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-media_center slds-media_small slds-listbox__option_plain" data-item-id="combobox-button-32-9" data-value="Calle" role="option" id="combobox-button-32-9-32" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span><span class="slds-media__body"><span class="slds-truncate" title="Calle">Calle</span></span></lightning-base-combobox-item><lightning-base-combobox-item lwc-4kb6kaqheak="" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-media_center slds-media_small slds-listbox__option_plain" data-item-id="combobox-button-32-10" data-value="Plaza" role="option" id="combobox-button-32-10-32" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span><span class="slds-media__body"><span class="slds-truncate" title="Plaza">Plaza</span></span></lightning-base-combobox-item></div></div></div></lightning-base-combobox></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automate shadow DOM elements using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.