# My bot can't locate a wierd button element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I recently started doing botting to try and get my hands on a better graphics card. My issue is this button: [button html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZx0T.png) which has no name or anything useful that would allow my bot to detect it. I have tried using its XPath but to no success. [my XPath attempt (I used the real XPath don't worry)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGvcv.png). Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: It's in a shadow root. You need to driver.execute() and return the .shadowroot of the element.

Comment: As mentioned I am very new. How exactly would I go about doing so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384458/how-to-handle-elements-inside-shadow-dom-from-selenium

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("core-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("a")').click()
```

use execute_script and then return the element inside the shadowRoot

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to fix my issue.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
def expand_shadow_element(element):
shadow_root = browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
return shadow_root

root1 = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('app-shell')
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)
    
root2 = shadow_root1.find_element_by_css_selector('request-page')
shadow_root2 = expand_shadow_element(root2)

root3 = shadow_root2.find_element_by_css_selector('box-content')
shadow_root3 = expand_shadow_element(root3)

pay_button = shadow_root3.find_element_by_css_selector("core-button")
pay_button.click()
```