# Chrome Browser Headless problem : no such element: Unable to locate element at chrome://downloads/

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

due to some scenarios, I need to access chrome://downloads/
by headless mode but I got the error that looks like this:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#useragent"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.124)
```

After trying to search around and try much time, but failed
I've added a lot of options for chrome as below:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()

options.addArguments('--headless', '--start-maximized', '--window-size=1366,768', 'disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled', 
    'privileged', '--test-type', '--disable-gpu', '--no-first-run', '--no-default-browser-check', '--ignore-certificate-errors', 
    '--disable-extensions', '--proxy-bypass-list=*', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--no-sandbox', '--lang=en_US', '--allow-running-insecure-content')

options.addArguments('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36')

options.setExperimentalOption('useAutomationExtension', false)

options.setExperimentalOption('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])

options.addArguments('--proxy-server=\'direct://\'')

System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', ((RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + '\\Data Files\\builds\\chromedriver_') + 
    GlobalVariable.chromeDriverVersion) + '.exe')

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options)

driver.navigate().to('chrome://version/')

WebElement userAgent = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('#useragent'))

String txtUserAgent = userAgent.getText()

println(txtUserAgent)
```

But no luck happened

So anyone could help to resolve this problem, thanks a lot!
PS:  It can work fine on normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything inside `Chrome://downloads/` is under Shadow-root. You cannot directly access them.

Moreover, you'd see there are lot of nested shadow elements in DOM.

I have found a very good example here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384458/how-to-handle-elements-inside-shadow-dom-from-selenium) on how to access Shadow elements.

```
def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root
```

Comment: yeah, I already got the element by shadow dom already, It works on normal mode, but headless mode doesn't work, 
for the better example, at the chrome://version/ when no shadow dom here, it can't work in headless mode also, 
thanks!

Comment: Can you show some code ? That code that you shared is basically a config of driver.

Comment: Sorry, how can i post a long comment :(

Comment: looks like some issue with headless mode,  I could not even print `print(driver.title)` whereas without headless mode, it works.

Comment: more strange, I tried this `print(len(driver.find_elements(By.ID, "useragent")))` and it is printing '0' that explains nosuch element exception, but I am not sure when it is only not working with headless mode, ideally it should. could be a bug

Comment: yes, yay! thank you.
so I should wait for the next fixing?

Comment: Is headless really required for this use case ?

Comment: ah, actually I'm trying to automate the "Browser",  it needs a lot of tip&trick should be used, 
sometimes I need to get the element, value... in silent mode for e.g
But the normal mode is OK for now, I will wait for the next fixing if any, anyway thank you so much! have a great day!