# Selenium cannot find element in webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am having some trouble trying to automate some web inputs, but first i need to click some buttons and i cannot do it. I've tried a lot of stuff but i cannot complete it :'(

webpage: https://vacunacovid.catsalut.gencat.cat/

I cannot go past the image the code i have:

> ```
> rom selenium import webdriver
> from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
> from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> import time
>
> # browser config
> options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
> options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
> options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
> driver_path= "/C:/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver" # este es el driver del navegador https://chromedriver.chromium.org/
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path,chrome_options=options)
>
> #starting screen in optimal position
> driver.set_window_position(2000,0)
> driver.maximize_window()
> time.sleep(1)
>
> #getting website
> driver.get("https://vacunacovid.catsalut.gencat.cat/")
>
> #go to the element if its clickable
> WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
>     .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, BLABLABLA)))\
>     .click()
> ```

it doesn't find anything throwugh this #shadow (open) , how can i do it?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/it2nQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is under `Shadow-dom` #shadow-root (open) So you have not mentioned exactly which button you want to click, so I'm clicking on the first button `Demana o modifica cita`

```
#adding some wait for application to load properly
sleep(5)
```

You just take the JS path of the desire element as below and return the element for that

press F12->Element Tab -> right click(on the element)->copy JS path

```
javascript = 'return document.querySelector("body > vaccinapp-app").shadowRoot.querySelector("#pages > vaccinapp-shell").shadowRoot.querySelector("#main-shell-content > appointment-shell").shadowRoot.querySelector("#appointment-shell-content > appointment-onboarding").shadowRoot.querySelector("#dismiss-btn").shadowRoot.querySelector("#button")'
```

By using `execute_script` will access the element under shadow-root (open)

```
element = driver.execute_script(javascript)
element.click()
```

**code**

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
driver_path= "/C:/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path,chrome_options=options)

#starting screen in optimal position
driver.set_window_position(2000,0)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)

#getting website
driver.get("https://vacunacovid.catsalut.gencat.cat/")
sleep(5)
javascript = 'return document.querySelector("body > vaccinapp-app").shadowRoot.querySelector("#pages > vaccinapp-shell").shadowRoot.querySelector("#main-shell-content > appointment-shell").shadowRoot.querySelector("#appointment-shell-content > appointment-onboarding").shadowRoot.querySelector("#dismiss-btn").shadowRoot.querySelector("#button")'
element = driver.execute_script(javascript)
element.click()
```

[For reference](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/beyond-dom-legacy-selenium-selectors-rise-shadow-virender-singh) [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384458/how-to-handle-elements-inside-shadow-dom-from-selenium)

Comment: @Ague if it helps you, please accept the answer, So it would be helpful for others