# How to click on a button that does not appear on page source?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to click on a button using Selenium with Python, however the button does not appear on Page Source and thus, the instantiated driver cannot find it. Here is the link I am accessing: https://data.ntsb.gov/carol-main-public/query-builder?month=6&year=2021

And the button I want to click is "Download Summary (CSV)", which is located at the end of the page.

I have already googled this kind of trouble but I haven't found a possible solution so far.

My attempt was to find the button directly by using the following commands, but it returns a NoSuchElementException:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('exportSummaryButton')
element.click()
```

This exception triggered me the intuition that the page source differs from what I see on Devtools and this is exactly what happens.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: @DonnyFlaw I have just edited my question with my attempt. Thanks

Comment: Since button located inside shadow-root you need to use [specific approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384458/how-to-handle-elements-inside-shadow-dom-from-selenium). Or it's better to use API-request to download file

Comment: I will try the approach described in the link! Regarding the API-Request, I'm not sure what the endpoint should be... could you please provide more details? Thank you!

Comment: You need to execute API request to https://data.ntsb.gov/carol-main-public/api/Query/FileExport