# Selenium & BeautifulSoup cannot find Fields table elements within #shadow_root

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, shadow-root

I have been trying to scrape data from the following site: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.netzero_cloud_dev_guide.meta/netzero_cloud_dev_guide/sforce_api_objects_airtravelemssnfctr.htm#maincontent.

I want to obtain the Fields table but nothing seems to be working. Anytime I try to get any element from the site I get the following error:
'NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element'

I have tried everything!

Some things I have tried:

```
driver.get('https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.netzero_cloud_dev_guide.meta/netzero_cloud_dev_guide/sforce_api_objects_airtravelemssnfctr.htm')
driver.find_element("name", "featureTable sort_table")

driver.get('https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.netzero_cloud_dev_guide.meta/netzero_cloud_dev_guide/sforce_api_objects_airtravelemssnfctr.htm')
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="maincontent"]/doc-xml-content//doc-content-layout/doc-content//div/div[1]/div[3]/div/table')
```

And many more. I have also tried WebDriverWait to let the page load and attempted to change to iframe but I don't think there is one as I cannot find an iframe name or ID.

Anything helps! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Element you are trying to access is inside the `shadow-rot`.
There are several techniques to access such elements.
You can find here several questions dealing with it, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384458/how-to-handle-elements-inside-shadow-dom-from-selenium):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### [***shadow_root***](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.shadow_root)

The *`shadow_root`* attribute returns a shadow root of the element if there is one or an error. Only works from Chromium 96 onwards. Previous versions of Chromium based browsers will throw an assertion exception.

---

### Solution

Using [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) ***v96*** (and above) and [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) to access the ***Fields*** table, as the table element is within multiple [#shadow-root (open)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56380091/7429447) you can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.netzero_cloud_dev_guide.meta/netzero_cloud_dev_guide/sforce_api_objects_airtravelemssnfctr.htm#maincontent'})
  shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'doc-xml-content')
  shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
  shadow_child = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'doc-content')
  shadow_grand_child = shadow_child.shadow_root
  element = shadow_grand_child.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.featureTable')
  print(element.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <table class="featureTable sort_table" summary="">


                 <thead class="thead sorted" align="left">
                    <tr>
                       <th class="featureTableHeader  " id="d51659e96">Field</th>

                       <th class="featureTableHeader  " id="d51659e99">Details</th>

                    </tr>

                 </thead>

                 <tbody class="tbody">
                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">Ch4PsgrKmLongHaulInKgCo2e</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">double</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">Create, Filter, Nillable, Sort, Update</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>

                                <dd class="dd"> The CH4 emissions per passenger-kilometer in CO2e from long-haul
                                   flights. </dd>


                          </dl>

                       </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">Ch4PsgrKmMediumHaulInKgCo2e</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">double</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">Create, Filter, Nillable, Sort, Update</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>

                                <dd class="dd"> The CH4 emissions per passenger-kilometer in CO2e from
                                   medium-haul flights. </dd>


                          </dl>

                       </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">DistanceUnit</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">picklist</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">Create, Defaulted on create, Filter, Group, Nillable, Restricted
                                   picklist, Sort, Update</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>

                                <dd class="dd"> The unit of measure for the distance. </dd>

                                <dd class="dd">Possible values are: <ul class="ul bulletList">
                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">Kilometers</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">Miles</samp></li>

                                   </ul>

                                </dd>

                                <dd class="dd">The default value is 'Kilometers'.</dd>


                          </dl>

                       </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">EmissionFactorDataSource</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">textarea</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">Create, Nillable, Update</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>

                                <dd class="dd"> The source of the emissions factor reference data. </dd>


                          </dl>

                       </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">EmissionFactorUpdateYear</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">picklist</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">Create, Filter, Group, Nillable, Restricted picklist, Sort,
                                   Update</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>

                                <dd class="dd"> The year in which this reference data for the emissions factor
                                   was most recently updated. </dd>

                                <dd class="dd">Possible values are: <ul class="ul bulletList">

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2000</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2001</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2002</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2003</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2004</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2005</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2006</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2007</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2008</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2009</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2010</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2011</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2012</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2013</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2014</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2015</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2016</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2017</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2018</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2019</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2020</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2021</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2022</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2023</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2024</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2025</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2026</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2027</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2028</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2029</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2030</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2031</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2032</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2033</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2034</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2035</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2036</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2037</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2038</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2039</samp></li>

                                      <li class="li"><samp class="codeph nolang">2040</samp></li>

                                   </ul>

                                </dd>


                          </dl>

                       </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">LastReferencedDate</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">dateTime</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">Filter, Nillable, Sort</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">The timestamp for when the current user last viewed a record
                                   related to this record.</dd>


                          </dl>

                       </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">LastViewedDate</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">dateTime</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">Filter, Nillable, Sort</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">The timestamp for when the current user last viewed this record.
                                   If this value is null, this record might only have been referenced
                                   (LastReferencedDate) and not viewed. </dd>


                          </dl>

                       </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">LongHaulMinimumDistance</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">double</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">Create, Filter, Nillable, Sort, Update</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>

                                <dd class="dd"> The minimum distance for a long-haul flight that’s adjusted
                                   according to the short-haul or medium-haul distances. </dd>


                          </dl>

                       </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">MediumHaulMaximumDistance</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">double</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">Create, Filter, Nillable, Sort, Update</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>

                                <dd class="dd"> The maximum distance of a medium-haul flight. </dd>


                          </dl>

                       </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">N2oPsgrKmLongHaulInKgCo2e</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">double</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">Create, Filter, Nillable, Sort, Update</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>

                                <dd class="dd"> The N2O emissions per passenger-kilometer in CO2e from long-haul
                                   flights. </dd>


                          </dl>

                       </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">N2oPsgrKmMediumHaulInKgCo2e</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">double</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">Create, Filter, Nillable, Sort, Update</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>

                                <dd class="dd"> The N2O emissions per passenger-kilometer in CO2e from
                                   medium-haul flights.</dd>


                          </dl>

                       </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">N2oPsgrKmShortHaulInKgCo2e</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">double</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">Create, Filter, Nillable, Sort, Update</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>

                                <dd class="dd"> The N2O emissions per passenger-kilometer in CO2e from short-haul
                                   flights.</dd>


                          </dl>

                       </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">N2oPsgrMileLongHaulInKgCo2e</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">double</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">Create, Filter, Nillable, Sort, Update</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>

                                <dd class="dd"> The N2O emissions per passenger-mile in CO2e from long-haul
                                   flights. </dd>


                          </dl>

                       </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">N2oPsgrMileMediumHaulInKgCo2e</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">double</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>

                                <dd class="dd">Create, Filter, Nillable, Sort, Update</dd>



                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>

                                <dd class="dd"> The N2O emissions per passenger-mile in CO2e from medium-haul
                                   flights.</dd>


                          </dl>

                       </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">N2oPsgrMileShortHaulInKgCo2e</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>
                                <dd class="dd">double</dd>
                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>
                                <dd class="dd">Create, Filter, Nillable, Sort, Update</dd>
                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>

                                <dd class="dd"> The N2O emissions per passenger-mile in CO2e from short-haul
                                   flights.</dd>
                          </dl>

                       </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">Name</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">

                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>
                                <dd class="dd">string</dd>
                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>
                                <dd class="dd">Create, Filter, Group, idLookup, Sort, Update</dd>
                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>
                                <dd class="dd">Name of the account.</dd>
                          </dl>
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">OwnerId</span></td>

                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">
                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>
                                <dd class="dd">reference</dd>
                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>
                                <dd class="dd">Create, Defaulted on create, Filter, Group, Sort, Update</dd>
                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>
                                <dd class="dd">The ID of the user who owns this record. </dd>
                                <dd class="dd">This is a polymorphic relationship field.</dd>
                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Relationship Name</dt>
                                <dd class="dd">Owner</dd>
                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Relationship Type</dt>
                                <dd class="dd">Lookup</dd>
                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Refers To</dt>
                                <dd class="dd">Group, User</dd>
                          </dl>
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e96" data-title="Field"><span class="keyword parmname">ShortHaulMaximumDistance</span></td>
                       <td class="entry" headers="d51659e99" data-title="Details">
                          <dl class="dl detailList">
                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Type</dt>
                                <dd class="dd">double</dd>
                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Properties</dt>
                                <dd class="dd">Create, Filter, Nillable, Sort, Update</dd>
                                <dt class="dt dlterm">Description</dt>
                                <dd class="dd"> The maximum distance of a short-haul flight. </dd>
                          </dl>
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
                  </table>
  ```