# How to access the Fields table elements within multiple Shadow Dom using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, shadow-dom

I have been trying to scrape data from the following site using Selenium & Python: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.netzero_cloud_dev_guide.meta/netzero_cloud_dev_guide/sforce_api_objects_airtravelemssnfctr.htm#maincontent.

I want to obtain the **Fields** table but nothing seems to be working. Anytime I try to get any element from the site I get the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

It has since been pointed out to me that the reason this is occurring is because the element I want to access is inside 2 `#shadow-root (open)`. I am having trouble figuring out how to access this.

I am referencing this article: [How to handle elements inside Shadow DOM from Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384458/how-to-handle-elements-inside-shadow-dom-from-selenium). However, I am having a hard time altering the code for my needs.

Does anyone know how I can access the element I need behind the Shadow DOM? Desperately need help with this as I cannot figure it out.

Attempting to use the code below but I can't figure out which elements I should be referencing in each root variable in the find_element_by_id function. If anyone has advice on how

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root

driver.get("chrome://settings")
root1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('settings-ui')
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)

root2 = shadow_root1.find_element_by_css_selector('[page-name="Settings"]')
shadow_root2 = expand_shadow_element(root2)

root3 = shadow_root2.find_element_by_id('search')
shadow_root3 = expand_shadow_element(root3)

search_button = shadow_root3.find_element_by_id("searchTerm")
search_button.click()

text_area = shadow_root3.find_element_by_id('searchInput')
text_area.send_keys("content settings")

root0 = shadow_root1.find_element_by_id('main')
shadow_root0_s = expand_shadow_element(root0)

root1_p = shadow_root0_s.find_element_by_css_selector('settings-basic-page')
shadow_root1_p = expand_shadow_element(root1_p)

root1_s = shadow_root1_p.find_element_by_css_selector('settings-privacy-page')
shadow_root1_s = expand_shadow_element(root1_s)

content_settings_div = shadow_root1_s.find_element_by_css_selector('#site-settings-subpage-trigger')
content_settings = content_settings_div.find_element_by_css_selector("button")
content_settings.click()
```

Comment: Have you checked all SO answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=shadowdom%20selenium

Comment: Which website do you want to deal with `https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.netzero_cloud_dev_guide.meta/netzero_cloud_dev_guide/sforce_api_objects_airtravelemssnfctr.htm#maincontent` or `chrome://settings`?

Answer (score 1):

@JenPal An example with ShadowRoot for the same website is below. This should help arrive at a solution in your case. Make sure your Selenium version is 4.x:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=s)

driver.get(
    "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.netzero_cloud_dev_guide.meta/netzero_cloud_dev_guide/sforce_api_objects_airtravelemssnfctr.htm#maincontent")
main_content = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "main[id='maincontent'] doc-xml-content")
main_content_shadow_root = main_content.shadow_root
doc_content = main_content_shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "doc-content")
doc_content_shadow_root = doc_content.shadow_root;
table = doc_content_shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".featureTable.sort_table")
print(table.tag_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The *`<table>`* element with heading **Fields** is within multiple [#shadow-root (open)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56380091/7429447).

[image: table_shadow_root]

---

### Solution

To extract the contents of the table you have to use [`shadowRoot.querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793) and you can use the following [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.netzero_cloud_dev_guide.meta/netzero_cloud_dev_guide/sforce_api_objects_airtravelemssnfctr.htm#maincontent'})
  time.sleep(5)
  table_data = driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('doc-xml-content').shadowRoot.querySelector('doc-content').shadowRoot.querySelector('table.featureTable')""")
  print(pd.read_html(table_data.get_attribute("outerHTML")))
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [                            Field                                            Details
  0       Ch4PsgrKmLongHaulInKgCo2e  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  1     Ch4PsgrKmMediumHaulInKgCo2e  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  2      Ch4PsgrKmShortHaulInKgCo2e  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  3     Ch4PsgrMileLongHaulInKgCo2e  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  4   Ch4PsgrMileMediumHaulInKgCo2e  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  5    Ch4PsgrMileShortHaulInKgCo2e  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  6           Co2PsgrKmLongHaulInKg  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  7         Co2PsgrKmMediumHaulInKg  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  8          Co2PsgrKmShortHaulInKg  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  9         Co2PsgrMileLongHaulInKg  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  10      Co2PsgrMileMediumHaulInKg  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  11       Co2PsgrMileShortHaulInKg  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  12                   DistanceUnit  Type  picklist  Properties  Create, Defaulted ...
  13       EmissionFactorDataSource  Type  textarea  Properties  Create, Nillable, ...
  14       EmissionFactorUpdateYear  Type  picklist  Properties  Create, Filter, Gr...
  15             LastReferencedDate  Type  dateTime  Properties  Filter, Nillable, ...
  16                 LastViewedDate  Type  dateTime  Properties  Filter, Nillable, ...
  17        LongHaulMinimumDistance  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  18      MediumHaulMaximumDistance  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  19      N2oPsgrKmLongHaulInKgCo2e  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  20    N2oPsgrKmMediumHaulInKgCo2e  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  21     N2oPsgrKmShortHaulInKgCo2e  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  22    N2oPsgrMileLongHaulInKgCo2e  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  23  N2oPsgrMileMediumHaulInKgCo2e  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  24   N2oPsgrMileShortHaulInKgCo2e  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...
  25                           Name  Type  string  Properties  Create, Filter, Grou...
  26                        OwnerId  Type  reference  Properties  Create, Defaulted...
  27       ShortHaulMaximumDistance  Type  double  Properties  Create, Filter, Nill...]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For an unknown levels of `shadowRoot` you need to "Walk the DOM" and **dive** into shadowRoots:

```html
<my-component>
  #shadow-root(open)
  <my-component>
    #shadow-root(open)
    <my-component>
      #shadow-root(open)
      <content>
        <p>..text..</p>
      </content>
    </my-component>
  </my-component>
</my-component>

<script>
customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({mode:"open"}).innerHTML = `<slot></slot>`;
  }
})

const shadowDive = (
  el,
  selector,
  match = (el, root) => {
    console.warn('match', el, root);
  },
  root = el.shadowRoot || el
) => {
  root.querySelector(selector) && match(root.querySelector(selector), root);
  [...root.querySelectorAll("*")].map(el => shadowDive(el, selector, match));
}
shadowDive(document.body, "content"); // note optional parameters
</script>
```